# I have an arrray. I want to show each array in new line in React Native. How can I do this?

Tags: arrays, firebase, react-native

Here my situation

I want to add each index in a separate row but my record is shown in the same row as that **EnglishMathWeb**

demo

```
const Subject = ["English","Math","Web"] 

{Subject ? Subject.map((item,i)=>{
       
        <Text key={i}>{item}</Text>
        }
 ): <></>}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  {
    Subject.map((item, i)=>(
    <Text key={i}>{item}</Text>
    )
   )
  }
</View>
```